# How do I make an infinite repeat loop in jQuery or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to implement a jQuery or JavaScript infinite repeat loop with images inside a div.
Five images move only once in left and this is the end.
I would like to move five images an infinite repeat loop.
Can you help me with my code, please?

Regards.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
<div class="photobanner">
    <div id="photoSlider">
        <div class="photos">
            <img src="images/01.jpg" style="margin-top: 15px" />
            <img src="images/02.jpg" style="margin-top: 15px" />
            <img src="images/03.jpg" style="margin-top: 15px" />
            <img src="images/04.jpg" style="margin-top: 15px" />
            <img src="images/05.jpg" style="margin-top: 15px" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function infinite() {
        var elem = document.getElementById("photoSlider");
        elem.appendChild(elem.children[i].cloneNode(true));
      setTimeout(infinite, 1);
    }
</script>
```

My CSS:

http://pastebin.com/hS3C5ns4

Comment: You mean like this? http://wowslider.com/carousel-slider-showy-carousel-demo.html

Comment: At least you have the code to move to right and left? .... what you have tried

Comment: I've always liked owl carousel: http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/autoplay.html

Comment: Only move to left.

Comment: Use a marquee... Or more seriously just use CSS, e.g https://css-tricks.com/infinite-all-css-scrolling-slideshow/

Comment: I don't wanna carousel. I would like this effect: http://jsfiddle.net/P2GxE/2/

Comment: An infinitely executed JS loop won't let browser to update the view, hence you would never see your animation. A proper way would be to use [animation request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) or a [timer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers).

Comment: On site: http://jsfiddle.net/P2GxE/2/ only two images move in left, but is infinite repeat. In my code are five images, but move only once in left and this is the end.

Comment: That is done with a timer (setInterval).

Comment: It is a good site: https://progrower.coffeecup.com/picmarquee.html ---> 25 images move in left, but is infinite repeat. There is good, but in my code are five images, but move only once in left and this is the end. Where is error in my code?

Comment: *Where is error in my code?*  You don't have any code. You have a comment asking *How to write a jQuery or JavaScript?* You need to post your code in the question itself if you want debugging help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use several JQuery slider plugins available online. The functionality you are trying to achieve is very much common and use of a plugin ensures all case scenarios are well handled without you having to worry about some defect in what you developed. One of the popular ones that you can use is https://amazingslider.com/. There are other options as well. Just explore and decide!!